# Position images displayed-inline

Tags: html, css

Im trying to position the 3 phone icons to the bottom right. Underneath the bottom right image.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/grundysf/gksSy/15/)

Just when I think I have it by using for example margin-left xxpx, etc the images move over but then go vertically aligned.  What is best practice for positioning something anywhere you want it?

```
.imgs {

display:inline;
margin: 0px auto;
margin-left: 1002px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
.images {
    float:right;
}
```

or

```
.imgs {
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

in second case you can give spacing between two images also. `margin-left:10px;`

Comment: this moves them to the right, but they are fixed on the page.  Also is there a way to position them by pixels e.g. right: 800px, etc?

Comment: yes you can use it, but it is a bad practice to use such a huge amount of pixels to position your element.

Comment: now if you find this answer correct then please tick mark it as correct answer.

Comment: what would best practice be, maybe to apply a footer?

Comment: `float:right` takes your contents to extreme right where as margin-right:800px will create conflicts for **resposive design** (i.e. when you see your page on different resolutions)

Answer (score 0):

```
.images > div {
    display: inline-block;
    float:right
}
```